# ploting multiple histogram in same figure with different color in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

i have a 600x24 matrix a, i want to make histogram of each column in same figure but with differnet color in MATLAB,  i used the following code but it did not give me rainbow color,i used the following code, please help

```
col = hsv(24);

hold on;

for m = 1:24
hist(a(:,m), 50);
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(h,'FaceColor', col(m,:),'EdgeColor',col(m,:));
alpha(0.3);
end

hold off;
```

Answer (score 6):

The MATLAB `hist()` function works on matrices, and processes each column of the matrix separately. The `bar()` function can be used to plot the histogram yourself, and color the entries appropriately. Therefore you should be able to achieve the result using

```
[h,x] = hist(a,50); % histogram of every column and the bins vector
bar(x,h);           % plot histograms

% create a legend
l = cell(1,24);
for n=1:24, l{n} = num2str(n), end;
legend(l);
```